# ASP.NET MVC 4 | Entity Framework

Tags: audio

sorry for my english. i am junior developer. i have one question in **ASP.Net MVC 4 
entity framework**.

```
public class ClientContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }


}
```

Clients are stored in table "Clients". but Iam have also one table "GoodClients".And under different terms I need insert Client in one of tables. Can I using this ClientContext?
 What i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to add the Boolean marker to `Client` class - `IsGoodClient` so you can work with your client table like this:

```
var goodClient = clientContextInstance.Clients.Where(e=>e.IsGoodClient);
var badClients = clientContextInstance.Clients.Where(e=>!e.IsGoodClient);
```

To convert the client from 'GoodClient' to 'BadClient' you can do like this:

```
var goodClient = clientContext.Clients.First(e=>e.IsGoodClient && e.Id == 1);
goodClient.IsGoodClient = false;
clientContextInstance.SaveChanges();
```

So you dont need to make new table for storing the GoodClients

**EDIT**

Other way is to add `GoodClients` dbSet to your context:

```
public class ClientContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GoodClient> GoodClients { get; set; }
}
```

**But it is the horrible idea, because you will store the same data in the different tables.**

Comment: thank you Maris. But I go the second way.
Am I right? I Need Class GoodClient and use Attribute - [Table("GoodClients")] ?

Comment: It's your choice, but I would strongly recommend to use the first way. If you will use the second way you will have more problems in the future, like compairing of 2 entities problem or dublicate entry of entity in 2 tables problem. Why you dislike the first way?

Comment: yes, you can do it like that. But actually attribute [Table("GoodClients")] here is redundant. EF will map your DbSet<GoodClient> to table GoodClients by it self.

Comment: Client from table "Clients" can moves to "GoodClients" and is removed from "Clients" or  just removed from "Clients". thus, I need the separation, because "Clients" is a temorary storage for Client. I hope you understand me.

Comment: thank you. you really help me. and I will call you, if I have question.